Eigenvalues of the Jack polynomials for the Calogero-Sutherland operator
The Calogero-Sutherland operator on the space of homogeneous symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables is defined by
$$
\frac{\alpha}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{1\leqslant i < j \leqslant n} \left(\frac{x_i+x_j}{x_i-x_j}\right)\left(x_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}-x_j\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right).
$$
It is claimed in the above link that the Jack polynomial $J^{(\alpha)}_\lambda$ of an integer partition $\lambda$ is an eigenpolynomial of this operator, with eigenvalue
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\lambda_i^2 + \frac{n+1-2i}{2} \right).
$$
This formula is not in agreement with the one given at page 10 of this paper, which claims that the eigenvalue is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\lambda_i^2 + \frac{n+1-2i}{2}\lambda_i \right).
$$
I implemented the Jack polynomials and I'm pretty sure my implementation is correct (I started to implement them a long time ago and the implementation has been intensively tested). However, I find that the Jack polynomials are indeed eigenpolynomials of this operator but none of the two above formulas are in agreement with the eigenvalues I get. For example, for $n=3$ and $\lambda=(2,1)$, I find the eigenvalue $\alpha + 2$.
So what is the correct expression of the eigenvalue?

There may an issue here with different definitions of the CS operator. The second expression for the eigenvalues in the OP is for a slightly different operator:
\begin{align}
&H=\frac{\alpha}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{1\leqslant i < j \leqslant n} \left(\frac{x_i+x_j}{x_i-x_j}\right)\left(x_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}-x_j\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right),
%&E_n=\sum_{j=1}^n\bigl(\lambda_j^2+\beta(n+1-2j)\lambda_j\bigr).
\end{align}
see Exact operator solution of the Calogero-Sutherland model. So this differs from the operator in the OP, which has $x_i^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}$ in the first sum.

Right, it works. And the correct formula is the second one. Thanks.
